# Shopify not showing collections for product tagging

Tags: shopify

For some reason my collections are not showing when I am creating a product.

[image]
I have created collections and made them available but why oh why are they not showing up. When i search for them next to the product? I have made the collections arable but only one there is home page?

[image]

Comment: Are there any products that are added to these collections, I think if they are empty until doesn't show?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has manual collections and Automated collections, Automated collections are those which will add products based on a condition, see on your screenshot how it says **product conditions**?

You can not add product manually to an Automated collection, it can only be done by making sure the product meets the condition. Hence, Shopify won't show those collections in the collection picker 'cuz that will be manually adding a product to an Automated collection, for example, add **straps** tag to a product and it will be atomically added to the Watch Straps collection.